# box-api search parameters not working?

Tags: java, search, parameters, sdk, box-api

I'm using the Java SDK to connect to Box.  I find the root folder (this is a small dev instance so I don't mind searching from there.)  I execute the search query and I get results. My problem is that the search parameters do not seem to work consistently or at all.

- For example, this query

  Iterator resultSet = rootFolder.search("query=NR_chewy_chic_swt_pot_app&file_extensions=jpg&content_type=name&type=file").iterator();

returns three entries.

```
NR_chewy_chic_swt_pot_app.jpg
NR Chewy Chicken AD02.xls
PreInvoice_M197301-3644756_NR Chewy Treats SURP.pdf
```

- I remove the substring "&file_extensions=jpg" because it doesn't seem to do anything and save/recompile/run and I get the same three results.
- I change "&type=file" to "&type=folder" and I get the same three results.
- I change "query=NR_chewy_chic_swt_pot_app" to "query=NR" and I get **NO** results.  Even though SO user Peter (who appears to work for Box) says that partial strings should match[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007065/filter-folder-listing-based-on-date).

I've tried rearranging the order of the search parameters to no avail.  What am I missing?

Thanks,
Eric B.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I didn't mind the title but maybe too self-deprecating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced search [has yet to be implemented](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/issues/13) in the SDK (since it's still in beta), but it will be added in the coming weeks.

The reason why your call doesn't work is because the query method parameter is sent as the ["query" URL parameter](https://developers.box.com/docs/#search) in the API call. Therefore, the ampersands in your query string are being escaped.

If you need an immediate workaround, you can use the [`BoxAPIRequest` and `BoxAPIResponse`](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/doc/overview.md#requests-and-responses) classes to make a custom search request. For example:

```
BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection("token");
URL url = new URL("https://api.box.com/2.0/search?query=NR_chewy_chic_swt_pot_app&file_extensions=jpg&content_type=name&type=file")
BoxAPIRequest request = new BoxAPIRequest(api, url, "GET");
BoxJSONResponse response = (BoxJSONResponse) request.send();
String json = response.getJSON();
```

Sorry that this wasn't clear. We'll update the documentation to make it more explicit that `query` represents the query field and not the URL query string.

Comment: I'm sure any ambiguity is in my head, not the documentation.  This is my first pass at Box so I'm still figuring out how to think about it.  Great answer!  I'll try it tomorrow.